# I got this warning in file uploading

Tags: php

I want to upload a word and PDF file and I got these errors as follows:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(public_html/Sourabh/php/uploadphp-all-in-one.doc): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/dtechnol/public_html/Sourabh/php/uploader.php on line 8
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpeZ0cHW' to 'public_html/Sourabh/php/uploadphp-all-in-one.doc' in /home/dtechnol/public_html/Sourabh/php/uploader.php on line 8
> Upload failed

Here is some more debugging info:

```
Array
(
[userfile] => Array
    (
        [name] => php-all-in-one.doc
        [type] => application/msword
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpeZ0cHW
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 1604096
    )

)
```

Comment: seems directory path is wrong

Comment: It means the path you have mentioned is wrong.. Once check the path again..  If your path is OK.
In Linux sometimes you have to change the permissions of the folders in which you are uploading.. Once check it too..

Comment: i also change the permissions of the folder 777 and i directly provide the  hard code path  path is home/dtechnol/public_html/Sourabh/php

Comment: check which extension files are allowed. is the extension you are injecting, Is that allowed or not.

Comment: better to show your code here. which are you using to upload the file

Comment: <?php

$uploaddir = 'upload/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

echo "<p>";

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
  echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
   echo "Upload failed";
}

echo "</p>";
echo '<pre>';
echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);
print "</pre>";

?>